# Whats wrong with my @font-face?

Tags: html, css, apache, web, lamp

Sorry if it's incorrect practice to post multiple problems, but:

I have a working @font-face set up, but when I set the font-weight inside @font-face, Firefox displays my default font instead of the one I defined in @font-face. Chromium doesn't even seem to work with @font-face in the first place...
And, I think due to me not being able to set the font-weight, the font (Lato Black) is way too bold.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Marco Scannadinari</title>
    <link href = "layout.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "centre">
      <div class = "lato-black">
        <h1>Marco Scannadinari</h1>
      </div>
      <div class = "cantarell">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

... And my CSS:

```
body {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 512px;
  margin-right: 512px;
}

div.centre {
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "lato-black";
  src: url("fonts/Lato-Bla.ttf")
  format("truetype")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "cantarell";
  src: local("fonts/Cantarell-Regular.otf")
  format("opentype")
}

div.cantarell {
  font-family: "cantarell";
}

div.lato-black {
  font-family: "lato-black";
  text-shadow: 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Using apache on Fedora 18 x86_64

Comment: I think you also need `woff` file type and you should set the font-weight in your `@font-face too`.

Comment: Try generating your font-face here : http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: @Jrod: But when font-weight is set, the browser defaults to its normal font for some reason.

Comment: @zheoffec You may have a mismatch between font-weights.  What value are you setting the font weight to?  If you set `font-weight` to `800` in your font-face you also need to set the font-weight on your class to the same to see the font.

Comment: @Jrod: I dont have the font resetting problem anymore, but the extralarge font (lato-black) seem way too bold still.

Comment: @Jrod: should font-weight be normal on all of the fonts (I now have (at)font-faces for every style (italic, bold, bold italic, etc)?

Comment: Here is a good example: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700,400italic,700italic There is normal, bold, normal italic and bold italic.

Comment: But if the font ((font)-bold) is already created as bold, then why would the font weight be higher - It is already bold, isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use different formats of fonts for different browsers. In the end you should have something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

Comment: maybe you have bold one be default? try to find something like "Lato-Black light"